# How to stop WordPress from using utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation

Tags: database, collation

I'm using WP Sync DB plugin for migrating sites between dev, stage and live.
Recently i ran in this problem: while creating a new instance on my local dev, WordPress created all tables with utf8mb4_unicode_ci. This leads to problems getting the data migrated. Also live servers often don't support utf8mb4 at all.

I already set `define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');` but WordPress ignoredt it on creation.

Any ideas?

Comment: not having support for utf8mb4 is an inexcusable security problem. No production setting should have any excuse for not running with it. Your question amounts to "how can I keep my sites not being secure?" :(

Comment: the best constructive criticism is packed in a sandwich of sarcasm. Nonetheless thanks for this important hint. I will try to get updated live systems now.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter every database query with the hook `query`, for example like this:

```
add_filter( 'query', function ( $query ) {
    return str_replace( 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 'utf8_unicode_ci', $query );
});
```

However, I would strongly recommend not to do this. Update your databases instead. The old `utf8_*` collations have very annoying limitations, and you will run into plugin compatibility problems with them.

And whatever you do, don't use the `general` variations. [They cannot sort properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/299509).